# Why solving Lyapunov’s equation proves the stability?

Tags: stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

The equation:

A'P + PA = -Q

where A is an n×n matrix, P is a symmetric positive-definite matrix of the same size, and Q is a symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix.

A is the matrix of the system.

I am trying to understand the lyapunov equation. Maybe it's a very stupid question. What does the matrix P represent? What is the origin of the equation? Why this prove the stability?

Comment: Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

Comment: [This will most likely](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Dynamic_Systems_and_Control_(Dahleh_Dahleh_and_Verghese)/14%3A_Internal_stability_for_LTI_systems/14.01%3A_Quadratic_Lyapunov_Functions_for_LTI_Systems) answer your question.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen thanks for your answer! It is clear!